# About adding a variable with itself and another variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addition

I am trying to make a clone of this one bot in discord but I am having problems with my code. This is my code

```
balance.bank.coins = balance.bank.coins + 
parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()* 500));
```

I want `balance.bank.coins` to be added with a random number **from 0 to 500** and each time it does it will keep adding up with the previous result. But every time I try to run it it's just the RNG part that works. It never adds up the previous results.

Comment: can you post the balance json how it looks like>

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you don't need to ParseInt because the function already returns a number. Secondly, maybe you're assigning balace.bank.coins somewhere earlier and that's why every time you run it you can't get it to add up? For example:

```
x = 10;
x = x + Math.floor(Math.random()* 500);
console.log(x)
//x gets added by x + random number
```

In this example every time I run this block x will always start as 10 because that's how I assigned it even though within this scope it does indeed get added (the output in the console.log).

Comment: I have tested it and ran the code. Unfortunately, it's still the same problem. It just randomizes the up to 500 and the result is the one that's logged. The X gets completely ignored, :(

Comment: Yes I said it would get ignored in the end because the execution is over and it gets reassigned to 10 when run again. Also if you make x = 1000 in the example you will see that it actually get's added.

Comment: Oh!! I see. Thank you so much. I understand now.